# Converting milliseconds to hh:mm format by considering the rounding in r

Tags: r, time, converters

I am trying to convert milliseconds to `hh:mm` format. I tried this below:

```
x<-c(3159763, 2839300, 3821900)

t.adj <- 0
final <- strftime(as.POSIXlt.numeric(x/1000, format="%OS", origin="1970-01-01") - t.adj*3600,
                  format="%R", tz="GMT")

> final
[1] "00:52" "00:47" "01:03"
```

The issue here is the first element actual value is `52 mins 38sec` so since it passes halfway, it should be `53 mins` as `00:53`. The second element is `47min 19sec` so it can stay as `00:47` and the last one is `1 H 3 Min 41 s` so it should be printed `01:04`.

Does anyone have any idea to fix it in this function or possibly have another solution to this rounding issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `round_date` from the `lubridate` package to round to the nearest minute after converting milliseconds to a `POSIXct` object and before formatting it with `strftime`

```
library(lubridate)

x <- c(3159763, 2839300, 3821900)
y <- as.POSIXct.numeric(x/1000, origin = '1970-01-01')
z <- lubridate::round_date(y, unit = 'minute')

strftime(z, format = '%R', tz='GMT')

[1] "00:53" "00:47" "01:04"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with(as.POSIXlt(x/1000, 'GMT', Sys.Date()),sprintf("%02d:%02d", hour,min+sec%/%30))

[1] "00:53" "00:47" "01:04"
```

EDIT:

You could do:

```
 sprintf("%02d:%02d",(y<-round(x / 60000)) %/% 60, y %% 60)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. one caveat I encountered was when it is let's say `59 mins 55secs` then it rounds to `00:60`. Instead, can we make it `01:00` ?